# TextView background is not filling whole View

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to set `TextView` background color but I found out that if I'm using `TextView` inside `RelativeLayout` and I set `center_in_parent` or `center_vertical` to my TextView, background color is not stretched to full height of the `View` (its cut out on bottom). Then text inside looks off-centered. Any suggestion why it is happening? I'm seeing it for a first time.

Code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="InfoText"
        style="@style/info_text"/>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check your parent view padding. If your parent view contains padding it may happen.

Comment: Yes it has but I cant use margin, because there is much complicated logic there and this View is inflated on few places. Inflate will not copy margins over

Answer (score 0):

Set this code maybe fix it

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```